# How can I activate a virtualenv virtual environment in the anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, command-prompt, virtual-environment

I am fairly new to using virtual environments for python projects but I have spent many hours trying to resolve this issue I've been having through various posts on this site and on others and have come up short. I have even resorted to uninstalling all python distributions and reinstalling with no luck.

I have the anaconda distribution of python installed on Windows 10. I have the problem that after I create a virtual environment, called venv, in a project folder I am unable to then activate this virtual environment using the anaconda prompt to install packages through pip. What I have done so far is as follows:

```
(base) C:\Users\[User]\Documents\GitHub\[project_folder]> virtualenv venv
```

This then successfully creates a virtual environment folder in my project folder called `venv`. Working in this directory I navigate to:

```
(base) venv> cd Scripts
(base) venv\Scripts> activate
```

There are a number of `activate` files to choose from and neither turns the environment from `base` to `env` as expected.

The reason I am using anaconda prompt as opposed to the standard command prompt or Windows PowerShell is because when I'm using the `pip install <package>` anywhere but in the anaconda prompt I get an error message that reads:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

I'm not sure what this means and have tried to do some googling to solve this issue but to no avail. Note I do not have this issue when working on python projects on my MacBook and I can easily enter virtual environments and install the packages there with no issues. I'm relatively new to Windows so perhaps I'm missing something here...?

An interesting observation is that I can enter any virtual environment I've created through Windows PowerShell but I encounter the pip problem described above when trying to install packages into this environment.

I'm desperate for some help resolving this issue as it's greatly hindering the work on all my projects, and unfortunately I cannot just use my MacBook to code either.

Comment: I think the easiest resolution is not to mix virtualenv and conda, just use conda to create environments. Why are you trying to mix them?

Comment: I'm following the instructions given to me by colleagues. They don't appear to have, or have encountered the same issues I am having

Comment: I've gone the route you suggest through the conda virtual environments, and I can confirm I can create and activate the virtual environments. But when I try to install any packages I get the TSL/SSL error I mention in my original post. What do I need to do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Don't use `pip` in conda environments, use `conda` to install packages. Do you need to use pip? As in, is the package not available from conda?

Comment: yeah I do need to use `pip` for certain packages unfortunately. Can I just alter my virtual environment manually by copying a `pip.exe` file into it?

Comment: No, I don't think that will work well. If you're using conda environments, then you can still pip install packages into the conda environment. Basically, I'm suggesting that you not use `virtualenv` at all and just use conda. Conda environments are stored in a common location on your computer and you can activate them for a particular shell with the `conda activate` command. Once the environment is activated, then you can use `pip` to install whatever packages you want, although `conda install` is generally preferred when possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I explained the issue I am now having in my previous comment - my bad. I have taken your advice and ditched `virtualenv` in favour of using Conda environments. I can create and activate conda environments with no issue. I can use the command `conda install` within these conda environments. However when I try to use `pip install` inside a conda environment I get the `SSL/TSL` error I mention in my original post. I NEED to be able to use the command `pip install` for packages that are not supported by `conda` e.g. `QuantLib-Python`...

Comment: ... this is only an issue inside a Conda environment. I am able to use `pip install` outside of a conda environment and I don't know what is stopping me from using this command within a virtual environment because, as stated previously, I don't have any of these issues on my MacBook.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Are you using the Anaconda prompt or the regular cmd prompt? It seems the former may fix the issue, see here: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1139#issuecomment-449860789 See also here for more troubleshooting tips: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#ssl-connection-errors

Answer (score 0):

use those command for python virtualenv

```
For activate 
WINDOWS: activate nameofvenv
LINUX, macOS: source activate nameofvenv

For deactivate 
WINDOWS: deactivate
macOS, LINUX: source deactivate
```

Comment: Hi, these commands aren't correct anymore. The new commands are `conda activate nameofenv` and `conda deactivate` on all the platforms.